# How to iterate over IDREFS values in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml that uses an IDREFS field. I need to extract those id to put their in their own element.

Here's the basic structure I think I need but I don't know what to use in the select functions.

```
<xsl:template match="node_With_IDREFS_field">
   <xsl:for-each select="EACH ID IN @idrefsField">
      <xsl:element name="newElement">
        <xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="THE IDREF"/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <!-- keep rest of content -->
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So the from this node

`<node_With_IDREFS_field idrefsField="id1 id2"/>`

The result would be

```
<node_With_IDREFS_field>
  <newElement ref="id1"/>
  <newElement ref="id2"/>
</node_With_IDREFS_field>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show us an example of your input .

Comment: Just did! Was probably writting it while you were typing your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *tokenize* the value of the `idrefsField` attribute. XSLT 1.0 has no native tokenize() function, so you need to call a recursive named template to do this for you:

```
<xsl:template match="node_With_IDREFS_field">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@idrefsField"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <newElement ref="{$token}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if your processor supports it, you could use the EXSLT [str:tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension function.

Comment: If I want to pass the actual name of newElement as a parameter, how would I do that? I've added <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'myname'"/>, paramter declaration in template and then <{$elementName} sentryRef="{$token}"/> but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use the [`xsl:element` instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element) in order to create an element with a calculated name, e.g.  `<xsl:element name="$elementName"/>`.

Comment: I did try that but then the result is an empty node 

`<xsl:element name="$elementName"><xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="$token"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>`

I get `<node_With_IDREFS_field/>`

Comment: Oh I was missing the {} for $elementName!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<xsl:template match="node_With_IDREFS_field">
    <xsl:element name="node_With_IDREFS_field">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@idrefsField,' ')">
            <xsl:element name="newElement">
                <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question is about XSLT 1.0. Your answer requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.