# Tokenize and compare dates in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a variable in xslt1.0 which contains dates with a separator like
";Aug 11, 2015 11:16;Aug 07, 2015 08:27;Aug12, 2015 15:14"
I want to tokenize this variable value and get the latest date and store it in a variable. Can someone please help me.

Comment: That's a lot of work. Which XSLT processor are you using? Some extension functions could be useful here.

Comment: I'm using Xalan processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xalan supports the EXSLT [str:tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) function, so that will take care of that. After that, you just need to sort the tokens by the individual date & time components, and grab the last one.

```
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($dates, ';')">
    <!-- sort by year -->
    <xsl:sort select="substring(., 9, 4)"/>
    <!-- sort by month -->
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', substring(., 1, 3)))" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- sort by day -->
    <xsl:sort select="substring(., 5, 2)"/>
    <!-- sort by time -->
    <xsl:sort select="substring(., 14, 4)"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that this will not work if your dates are not all in the same format (in your input, the last date does not have a space between month and day).

Comment: I'm getting an error at str:tokenize statement.(Transform Error-XSL Transformation Failed). I'm using Visual Studio8 for development. Included this in the stylesheet (xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str"). I'm building this stylesheet for Teamcenter application which according to documentation use Xalan.

Comment: @userksp I cannot debug code I cannot see, even if I wanted to. I suspect you're **not** using Xalan when you get that error?

Comment: Can you please show me any other way to do it without using str:tokenize. Pls tell if you want any other input from me

Comment: Please help me in this issue. I'm a starter in xslt, so couldn't think of any solution.. trying for last 2 days, and am desperate to find a solution

Comment: You can see an example of using a named recursive template for tokenizing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593114/how-to-iterate-over-idrefs-values-in-xslt-1-0/31593480#31593480 Not sure why you're asking for it. If you're using Xalan, you don't need it; if you're not using Xalan, why did you say you were?

Comment: The documentation says it uses 'Xalan-C  1.10', except for this i dont know much about xsl processors. I've seen the recursive template (in the link you have provided) you've written. Can you please show how to integrate the call to that template (tokenize) and the sorting logic you have given in this answer.

Comment: Xalan-C does **not** support the `str:tokenize()` function. As for your request, I already said it's a lot of work. Place the result of the tokenizing template inside a variable, change the type to node-set using the `exsl:node-set()` function (Xalan-C does support that), then sort it as shown above.