# XSLT Selecting specific child elements from multiple reoccurring duplicate headers

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I can usually find an answer to the question I'm asking but this one has really stumped me. I have an XSLT and an Input XML document where I need to pull a datetime from parent elements that all mimic eachother. How I have this formatted, it works 80% of the time, but the other 20% of the time it messes up and sends the wrong time due to multiple of the same status for the same unit being used. ALL field are variable, but unit status are set. (See XSLT).

**Problem** : The later time overwrites the earlier time when the file is submitted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <ApparatusEvents>
                <xsl:for-each select="/ICADLINK_EVENT/UN_HI_LIST/UN_HI">
                    <xsl:if test="UNIT_STATUS = 'DP' and DGROUP = 'SNR'">
                        <ApparatusEvent>
                            <Apparatus>
                                <xsl:value-of select="UNID"/>
                            </Apparatus>
                            <Type>Dispatch</Type>
                            <DateTime>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CDTS_TIMESTAMP/CDTS_DATETIME"/>
                            </DateTime>
                            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
                        </ApparatusEvent>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ApparatusEvents>
            <ApparatusEvents>
                <xsl:for-each select="/ICADLINK_EVENT/UN_HI_LIST/UN_HI">
                    <xsl:if test="UNIT_STATUS = 'ER' and DGROUP = 'SNR'">
                        <ApparatusEvent>
                            <Apparatus>
                                <xsl:value-of select="UNID"/>
                            </Apparatus>
                            <Type>Enroute</Type>
                            <DateTime>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CDTS_TIMESTAMP/CDTS_DATETIME"/>
                            </DateTime>
                            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
                        </ApparatusEvent>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ApparatusEvents>
            <ApparatusEvents>
                <xsl:for-each select="/ICADLINK_EVENT/UN_HI_LIST/UN_HI">
                    <xsl:if test="UNIT_STATUS = 'AR' and DGROUP = 'SNR'">
                        <ApparatusEvent>
                            <Apparatus>
                                <xsl:value-of select="UNID"/>
                            </Apparatus>
                            <Type>Arrived</Type>
                            <DateTime>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CDTS_TIMESTAMP/CDTS_DATETIME"/>
                            </DateTime>
                            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
                        </ApparatusEvent>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ApparatusEvents>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT** Input File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ICADLINK_EVENT version="1.0" creationdate="3/29/2016 8:34:57 AM">
<UN_HI_LIST>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:12:54</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:12:54</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E7</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>DP</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:13:54</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:13:54</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E7</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>ER</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:15:05</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:15:05</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E607</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>DP</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:15:05</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:15:05</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E607</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>ER</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:20:39</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:20:39</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E607</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>AR</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:21:19</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:21:19</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E7</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>AR</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
<UN_HI>
    <CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
        <CDTS_DATE>3/29/2016</CDTS_DATE>
        <CDTS_TIME>08:21:46</CDTS_TIME>
        <CDTS_DATETIME>3/29/2016 08:21:46</CDTS_DATETIME>
    </CDTS_TIMESTAMP>
    <UNID>E607</UNID>
    <UNIT_STATUS>AR</UNIT_STATUS>
    <DGROUP>SNR</DGROUP>
</UN_HI>
```

Current Output : (It sends the Arrived node for unit E607 twice, in which case it overwrites in the DB and and takes the latest time because it is the latest updated file.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Dispatch</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:12:54</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Dispatch</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:15:05</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Enroute</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:13:54</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Enroute</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:15:05</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Arrived</Type>
            <DateTime>**3/29/2016 08:20:39**</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Arrived</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:21:19</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Arrived</Type>
            <DateTime>**3/29/2016 08:21:46**</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
</soap:Body>
```

Desired Output : (I need it to only grab the earlier or later time for multiple status for the SAME unit)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Dispatch</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:12:54</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Dispatch</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:15:05</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Enroute</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:13:54</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Enroute</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:15:05</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents>
        **<ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E607</Apparatus>
            <Type>Arrived</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:20:39</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>**
        <ApparatusEvent>
            <Apparatus>E7</Apparatus>
            <Type>Arrived</Type>
            <DateTime>3/29/2016 08:21:19</DateTime>
            <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
        </ApparatusEvent>
    </ApparatusEvents>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
    <ApparatusEvents/>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without seeing your input. In general, this looks like a grouping problem, so start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Added Input File, (Whoops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize the example, let us concentrate on producing only your third `ApparatusEvents` branch. As I mentioned in the comments, this is a classic Muenchian grouping problem, with two complications.

The first complication is that you only want to consider *some* `UN_HI` elements - so you need to define a key that matches only these nodes (and you will have to define other keys for the other `ApparatusEvents` branches), and repeat the same predicate when calling this key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="key3" match="UN_HI[UNIT_STATUS='AR' and DGROUP='SNR']" use="UNID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <!-- skipped -->
            <ApparatusEvents>
                <xsl:variable name="records" select="/ICADLINK_EVENT/UN_HI_LIST/UN_HI[UNIT_STATUS='AR' and DGROUP='SNR']"/>
                <!-- for each distinct group -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$records[count(. | key('key3', UNID)[1]) = 1]">
                    <!-- get the earliest record in this group -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('key3', UNID)">
                            <xsl:sort select="CDTS_TIMESTAMP/CDTS_DATETIME" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                <ApparatusEvent>
                                    <Apparatus>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="UNID"/>
                                    </Apparatus>
                                    <Type>Arrived</Type>
                                    <DateTime>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="CDTS_TIMESTAMP/CDTS_DATETIME"/>
                                    </DateTime>
                                    <UnitCancelledFlag>false</UnitCancelledFlag>
                                </ApparatusEvent>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ApparatusEvents>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second complication is that sorting by `CDTS_DATETIME` will not produce a chronological order, because the format is not `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is unrelated to the main issue here, so I won't go into it. You can see an example of how to approach this here: [Tokenize and compare dates in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071733/tokenize-and-compare-dates-in-xslt-1-0/32074065#32074065)

Comment: Thank you, i'll need to look into Muenchian grouping and some other functions in XSLT like Key (Which I've never used).