# Replace Unique Character String with <xml> Tags in tidy up xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml message - created by a rather basic XML writer (it does not iterate repeating records under certain circumstances) - that has meant we have a text string that contains by necessity separated text chunks.
In the XML tool we were able to write one very long text string but we were able to add end of line/new line indicators. (TXNNTX but could be anything except a xml tag)
Being a  string it can be found anywhere in the XML file.

The string will be:

```
<causale>This is text that we need in line one TXNNTX We then need test to follow again that may have something important to say TXNNTX Then another line which is longer and longer and longer and longer and longer and longer and longer TXNNTX The maybe shorter TXNNTX or dots TXNNTX .............................................................................</causale>
```

We need to find the TXNNTX and replace it with   so the output becomes (new lines just for illustration):

```
<causale>This is text that we need in line one </causale>
<causale> We then need test to follow again that may have something important to say </causale>
<causale> Then another line which is longer and longer and longer and longer and longer and longer and longer </causale>
<causale> The maybe shorter </causale>
<causale> or dots </causale>
<causale> .............................................................................</causale>
```

The number of characters could be up to 2000 chars long
tried a number of different scripts but either because we are using "<"">" of the  within  appears to have confused my basic grasp of scripting

Comment: With XSLT 2 this is a job for `xsl:analyze-string`, with XSLT 3 you could do it a bit easier using the `analyze-string` function instead.  Find out whether you can use an XSLT or 3 processor like Saxon 9.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3 you could feed the result of the `analyze-string` function to a `for-each-group group-ending-with`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="marker" as="xs:string">TXNNTX</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="causale">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="analyze-string(., $marker)/*" group-ending-with="fn:match">
          <causale>
              <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[not(self::fn:match)]"/>
          </causale>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94Acsmp

Or process the result of the function with a different mode:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="marker" as="xs:string">TXNNTX</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:mode name="wrap" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="causale">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $marker)" mode="wrap"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="wrap" match="fn:non-match">
      <causale>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </causale>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94Acsmp/1

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply in XSLT 2.0 or higher by using the `tokenize()` function:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(causale, 'TXNNTX')">
    <causale>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </causale>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

If you're limited to XSLT 1.0, check if your processor supports the EXSLT [`str:split()`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html) extension function. If not, use a recursive template as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593114/how-to-iterate-over-idrefs-values-in-xslt-1-0/31593480#31593480), for example.